Trying to create networks with 100 nodes, variable no.of gateways using omnet FLoRa. How can I configure and automate it, to run all configurations?
I have multiple configuration files, which are to be automated in the sequence and the results to be recorded in individual .sca and .vec files. I am interested in analyzing the results for the parameters like Spreading Factor,Data Rate,Gateway Placement and Density, Gateway Antennae Configuration and Channel Allocation with the Adaptive Data Rate set and otherwise. Any help on this direction is much appreciated as I have started to work on omnet++ recently.
I am able to create a single configuration of a network, but not sure about the results part
